# Xamarin.Forms Blinking animation for an image in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can make my image flashing if Table from `TableList` has property `ShouldBlink` set to true.
I have FlexLayout where I'm populating it from `BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TableList}"`, where TableList is a list of tables

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" Wrap="Wrap" AlignContent="Start" AlignItems="Center" 
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TableList}" BackgroundColor="#313946"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <util:TableDisplayTemplateSelector TableTemplate="{StaticResource TableDataTemplate}" TabTemplate="{StaticResource TabDataTemplate}"/>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector>
</FlexLayout>
```

And this is how `TableDataTemplate` looks like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabDataTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type model:Table}">
            <StackLayout WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="60" Spacing="0">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding BindingContext.OpenExistingTableCommand, Source={x:Reference WorkingWithTablesPageContent}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image Source="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ConvertTableDataToIconFileName}}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

I need to make `Image` to flesh if Table from `TableList` has property `ShouldBlink` set to true.
I came up with DataTrigger like that to change backgroundColor if ShouldBlink is true, but cannot come up with the idea how to make it blink.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabDataTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type model:Table}">
        <StackLayout WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="60" Spacing="0">
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding BindingContext.OpenExistingTableCommand, Source={x:Reference WorkingWithTablesPageContent}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Image Source="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ConvertTableDataToIconFileName}}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Image.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding ShouldBlink}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean with blink? Just toggle visibility according to some rate, or something else? Please add some more information about what kind of animation you want to achieve.

Comment: I meant I want to make my image flashing if Table from TableList has property ShouldBlink set to true. (please see my edits in the post)

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Maybe can have a try with Attached properties ,will test in my local site . If works will update here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the way. I created class BlinkTriggerAction and used <DataTrigger.EnterActions> to execute this class.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabDataTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type model:Table}">
        <StackLayout WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="60" Spacing="0">
            <StackLayout.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout"  Binding="{Binding ShouldBlink}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <util:BlinkTriggerAction/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </StackLayout.Triggers>
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding BindingContext.OpenExistingTableCommand, Source={x:Reference WorkingWithTablesPageContent}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Image Source="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ConvertTableDataToIconFileName}}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>


public class BlinkTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    protected override async void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
    {
        var parentAnimation = new Animation();
        var fadeOutAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 1, 0, Easing.Linear);
        var fadeInAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 0, 1, Easing.Linear);
        parentAnimation.Add(0,0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
        parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
        parentAnimation.Commit(sender, "BlinkingVisualElement", 16, 1400, repeat:() => true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like charm!